# PhoneGap Android get the app version code

Tags: android, cordova, version

I am building a phonegap android app with jQueryMobile.

I want to build a function that checks the version code of the application with a webservice in order to suggest to update, if the app is outdated, prompting to the google play store.

From my searches, it looks like PhoneGap does not have a method for finding the *version code*.

Is there a way to do it:

- without writing anything in the Java classes?
- without manually storing an updated variable everytime I push a new version?

Or, if writing in the classes is essential, how do I call it from PhoneGap?

**EDIT: I edited the accepted answer with a working solution! I hope everybody can profit from it.**

**EDIT (2): and here is the full plugin repo with instructions, feel free to fork it :) https://github.com/gcatalfamo/Version**

Comment: The only way I see is either you add the version code to your app (e.g. variable)  or you develop a plugin on your own (see http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)

Comment: yes I was aware of those options, but I really really wanted to a) automate the version check and b) avoid creating a plugin..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you asked w/o writing Java Classes but one way or another you need to write one.  You need to write `PhoneGap Plugin` as Andre stated.

Create a custom `PhoneGap plugin`:

Create a new class in your app's package:

```
package com.phonegap.plugins; //your package name

import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult.Status;

public class Version extends Plugin {

    public final String ACTION_GET_VERSION_NAME = "GetVersionName"; //not used in this version
    public final String ACTION_GET_VERSION_CODE = "GetVersionCode";

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        PackageManager packageManager = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();
        if(action.equals(ACTION_GET_VERSION_CODE)) {
            try {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(this.cordova.getContext().getPackageName(), 0);
                result = new PluginResult(Status.OK, packageInfo.versionCode);
            }
            catch (NameNotFoundException nnfe) {
                result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, nnfe.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

In the plugins.xml, add the following line:

```
<plugin name="Version" value="your.package.Version" />
```

In your `deviceready` event add the following code:

```
var Version = function() {};
Version.prototype.getVersionCode = function(successCallback, failureCallback) {
    return cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'Version', 'GetVersionCode', []);
};

if(!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.version) {
    window.plugins.version = new Version();
}
```

Then, you can get the versionCode attribute by doing:

```
window.plugins.packageManager.getVersionCode(
    function(versionCode) {
        //do something with versionCode
    },
    function(errorMessage) {
        //do something with errorMessage
    }
);
```

Comment: you copy/pasted from another answer I already looked at...this plugin is not working because this.ctx.getPackageName() returns an error

Comment: @gcatalfamo : Resolved `this.ctx.getPackageName()`. Please check the edited code.

Comment: @gcatalfamo: Yeah I did c&p but the answer was in wrong place. So have to brought up thay on here[Right Place].

Comment: somehow it's still giving me an error, but I fixed it by putting the package name of my app as a string. It's not so elegant but it works!

Comment: I found a working generalized solution and edited your answer! Hope this helps everybody.

Comment: its giving me an  error The method getContext() is undefined for the type CordovaInterface in this line PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(this.cordova.getContext().getPackageName(), 0);

Answer (score 0):

a little change required .. class should extend " **extends CordovaPlugin** "

then "**this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName()**"  will work.

In the plugins.xml, add the following line:

BUT for Cardova > 2.0 ,  you need to add in **config.xml** inside **xml folder**